# Why is Python-nmap is not listing all_protocols() when I specify a port rage?

Tags: python, nmap, port-scanning

I am a beginner with Python and I cannot get nmap to list all the protocols:

```
import nmap
nmap_path = [r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe"]
nmScan = nmap.PortScanner(nmap_search_path=nmap_path)
nmScan.scan('127.0.0.1', '25-200')

# >>> {'nmap': {'command_line': '"C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Nmap\\\\nmap.exe" -oX - -p 25-200 -sV 127.0.0.1', 'scaninfo': {'tcp': {'method': 'syn', 'services': '25-200'}}, 'scanstats': {'timestr': 'Mon Nov  6 11:46:34 2023', 'elapsed': '37.95', 'uphosts': '1', 'downhosts': '0', 'totalhosts': '1'}}, 'scan': {'127.0.0.1': {'hostnames': [{'name': 'localhost', 'type': 'PTR'}], 'addresses': {'ipv4': '127.0.0.1'}, 'vendor': {}, 'status': {'state': 'up', 'reason': 'localhost-response'}}}}
```

```
nmScan['127.0.0.1'].all_protocols()

# >>> []
```

It works fine when I list the port range from 80-80 and I get:

```
import nmap
nmap_path = [r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe"]
nmScan = nmap.PortScanner(nmap_search_path=nmap_path)
nmScan.scan('127.0.0.1', '80-80')

# >>> {'nmap': {'command_line': '"C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Nmap\\\\nmap.exe" -oX - -p 80-80 -sV 127.0.0.1', 'scaninfo': {'tcp': {'method': 'syn', 'services': '80'}}, 'scanstats': {'timestr': 'Mon Nov  6 11:39:45 2023', 'elapsed': '2.78', 'uphosts': '1', 'downhosts': '0', 'totalhosts': '1'}}, 'scan': {'127.0.0.1': {'hostnames': [{'name': 'localhost', 'type': 'PTR'}], 'addresses': {'ipv4': '127.0.0.1'}, 'vendor': {}, 'status': {'state': 'up', 'reason': 'localhost-response'}, 'tcp': {80: {'state': 'filtered', 'reason': 'no-response', 'name': 'http', 'product': '', 'version': '', 'extrainfo': '', 'conf': '3', 'cpe': ''}}}}}
```

```
nmScan['127.0.0.1'].all_protocols()

# >>> ['tcp']
```

Comment: Is there documentation that explains what `all_protocols()` is supposed to to? I see an example on the homepage, but no detailed documentation.

Comment: My guess is it's returning the protocols that are open for all the ports in the range. Some are TCP, some are UDP, but no protocol is usable for all.

Comment: Hi, I could not find detailed explanations of the functions. Even when I follow the example as it is exactly shown on the homepage, I get an empty list for all_protocols().

Comment: It only works for port range 56-80.

Comment: You should ask the developer what this means.

Comment: This is not particularly useful information.  You aren't likely to find anything other than ICMP, TCP and UDP.